# Slim 3 - remove subdir from url with rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, slim-3

I have a shared hosting on A2Hosting and I recently moved my main domain from `public_html/` to `public_html/subdir/`

Here's the structure:

```
/public_html
 /subdir(site files of main domain)
  /api
  index.php
```

My current htaccess(public_html) is :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1 [L]
```

When I called my APi before it was : `domain.com/api/`

But now it's : `domain.com/subdir/api/`

My htaccess in `api` is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

How to remove the "subdir" in the url to keep my api like previous ? But still point the root to my subdir with my current htaccess ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you can change the basePath in the apache config easily

Comment: Hi @zedling , sorry I forgot to mention that I'm on shared hosting

Comment: I hope you did not move application files under public html

Comment: Hi @ZamronyP.Juhara, which application files you means ? All my files are on the subdir

Comment: What version of slim are you using here? Can you show your index.php code?

Comment: @Efbi - do you have a dedicated FQDN to this site? if you do, you could use VirtualHost with the same config you had, just point to a different DocumentRoot, you don't have to mess around the existing rewrite rules.  Let me know I can provide you a config example.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to rewrite `/api` from the main .htaccess file in the root directory like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ ../subdir/api/$1 [R,L,QSA]
```

The .htaccess file in the new /subdir/api folder can stays the way it is. Only the RewriteBase needs to be adjusted.

Another way is to rewrite from the previous `/api` folder if you preserved it for some reason:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../subdir/api/$1 [L]
```